# How can I import a Google Sketchup model with textures?

Tags: unity, textures, models

I'm using Unity 4 and trying to import a SketchUp Model into Unity and other Engines - but I can't get it to import correctly. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: No, dont work...

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't work?

Comment: When I put the 3d model gives it to me without the Texture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals [this question](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/99965-How-to-Import-a-Sketchup-%28-skp%29-Model-into-Unity-%28with-Textures%29) over on the Unity forums, the steps provided there are as follows:

> **Sketchup Standard version or Pro Version - v8 or higher:**
>
> - 1 Create/open the model with Google Sketchup
> - 2 Align the faces of the model (In the Monochrome mode--> the bright side should be up/front)
> - 3 Export in .dae format (Default settings!)
>
> **Blender - v3.55 or higher:**
>
> - 4 Open the .dae file with Blender (If you want to see the textures - switch to texture rendering mode)
> - 5 Export to .fbx (Default settings)
>
> **Unity - v3 or higher:**
>
> - 6 Create a new folder for your models (within the Assests tab) - Recommended
> - 7 Create a Folder called "Textures" within the new folder
> - 8 Drag/Import your model textures into the textures folder
> - 9 Drag/Import your .fbx model in the new folder (same layer as the "Textures" folder)
>
> If you have done everything right, you should see a materials folder
> (near the textures folder)  If you drag your object into the scene it
> should be fully textured If something is invisble - you have aligned
> the faces wrong (go back to step 2)
>
> PS: If you have Google Sketchup pro - you can skip the blender part

The basic idea being that you'll need to export through an intermediate format to get the textures working. Another step by step tutorial is [available here](http://bim.wikispaces.com/SketchUp+to+Unity+Workflow+Steps), which includes images to make things easier.

Comment: I did not understand this part: Align the faces of the model (In the Monochrome mode--> the bright side should be up/front)

Comment: View the question on the Unity forums, you'll find that question answered.

Comment: Unity can also import .dae files perfectly fine, and will convert them itself, so the Blender step is probably redundant.